# Any "for each" like hint

Tags: c++

I have two classes for example

```
struct point{
dint data
};

class data{
 ...
public:
 point left;
 point right;
 ..... //more that 50 members of point
 point some_other_point;

}example;
```

Is it possible use something like "for each `point` in `example`" in this situation?
Because now I need to modify many functions if I add one more `point` to `data`.
Or maybe, there is any other idea about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, and there are two ways to do so:

- an iterator class, for external iteration
- a visitation method, for internal iteration

Then the iteration logic is encapsulated in either of those classes and all the code just uses them.

---

Using the *iterator* class.

Pros:

- can easily be combined with existing STL algorithms, as well as `for` and `while` loops
- can suspend (and resume) iteration

Cons:

- requires polymorphism of attributes iterated over

Example:

```
class DataIterator;

class Data {
public:
    friend class DataIterator;

    Data(Point a, Point b, Point c): _one(a), _two(b), _three(c) {}

    DataIterator begin();
    DataIterator end();

private:
    Point _one; 
    Point _two;
    Point _three;
}; // class Data

class DataIterator:
    public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, Point>
{
public:
    struct BeginTag{};
    struct EndTag{};

    DataIterator(): _data(0), _member(0) {}

    DataIterator(Data& data, BeginTag): _data(&data), _member(0) {}
    DataIterator(Data& data, EndTag): _data(&data), _member(N) {}

    reference operator*() const {
        this->ensure_valid();
        MemberPtr const ptr = Pointers[_member];
        return _data->*ptr;
    }

    pointer operator->() const { return std::addressof(*(*this)); }

    DataIterator& operator++() { this->ensure_valid(); ++_member; return *this; }
    DataIterator operator++(int) { DataIterator tmp(*this); ++*this; return tmp; }

    friend bool operator==(DataIterator const& left, DataIterator const& right) {
        return left._data == right._data and left._member == right._member;
    }

    friend bool operator!=(DataIterator const& left, DataIterator const& right) {
        return not (left == right);
    }

private:
    typedef Point Data::*MemberPtr;

    static size_t const N = 3;
    static MemberPtr const Pointers[N];

    void ensure_valid() const { assert(_data and _member < N); }

    Data* _data;
    size_t _member;
}; // class DataIterator

//
// Implementation
//
DataIterator Data::begin() { return DataIterator(*this, DataIterator::BeginTag{}); }
DataIterator Data::end() { return DataIterator(*this, DataIterator::EndTag{}); }

size_t const DataIterator::N;

DataIterator::MemberPtr const DataIterator::Pointers[DataIterator::N] = {
    &Data::_one, &Data::_two, &Data::_three
};
```

And in case you wonder: [yes, it really works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e5716e58cc6ad68).

---

Using the visitation method, though, is easier.

Pros:

- can easily accommodate variance in the attributes types iterated over

Cons:

- cannot be combined with existing STL algorithms or existing loops
- pretty difficult to suspend the iteration part-way

Example:

```
class Data {
public:
    Data(Point a, Point b, Point c): _one(a), _two(b), _three(c) {}

    template <typename F>
    void apply(F&& f) {
        f(_one);
        f(_two);
        f(_three);
    }

private:
    Point _one; 
    Point _two;
    Point _three;
}; // class Data
```

And of course, [it works too](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9310365c24c3675a).

Comment: `template<typename T, typename M, M T::*...members> class DataIterator: public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, M>` would be tempting to me.

Comment: @Yakk: But it would not really be generic either, would it ? A class generally has an heterogeneous set of attributes. In fact, there is no difference between iterating over the members of a `class` and iterating over the elements of a `tuple`. And that is when, suddenly, polymorphism kicks and respecting the expectations of users on an iterator type become really difficult.

Comment: true: you can even reduce class member iteration to tuple iteration with a `make_tie` member function.  For a `tuple`, we could always iterate with a `value_type` of `boost::variant<X,Y,Z,...>` -- and require the caller to handle the problem.  No worse than the `for_each`, and the `for_each` version can be implemented in something like 5 lines on top of the `variant` iterator.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot enumerate members of a type, because C++ does not have the concept of *reflection*.

This is a common use case for an *array*, a *vector* or a *map*.

Comment: You can enumerate the members of a type in C++, you just have to work for it a bit. And certainly if multiple functions require iterating through attributes, the iteration logic can be shared among them whether it be "native" or "hand-made".

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
class data{
    public:

    enum POINTS {LEFT=0,RIGHT,SOME_OTHER_POINT};
    std::array<point,50> points; // or just point points[50];
 }example;
```

And use it like this:

```
example.points[data::LEFT]=point{};
```

Then you can iterate over points array with standard techniques.

Comment: Trick: `enum POINTS { ... , LAST_POINT, NUMBER_OF_POINTS }; std:array<point, NUMBER_OF_POINTS>;`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your current fields into:

```
private:
 point left;
 // ..

public:
 point& left() { return points[LEFT]; }
 // ..
```

where points might be an array of points (as in other answers), and LEFT is a constant index into array. This should allow for a relatively quick and painless transition, you will only have to add `()`, and compiler will output errors where to apply fixes.

Then you can convert your code to iterate your point values.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a for each function without modifying your example like this:

```
template<class Func>
void for_each_point(example& e, Func&& f){
  f(e.pt1);
  f(e.pt2);
  f(e.blah);
```

....

```
  f(e.last_pt);
}
```

and then call it like:

```
for_each_point(exam, [&](point & pt){
  std::cout<<pt.data<<"\n";
});
```

or do whatever in the body.

This function could also be a member variable, if you prefer.

Changing tye point storage to an array or `std::array` amd exposing `begin` and `end` or the array also works.

Finally, you could write a custom iterator that walks the points, but that is probably unwise.